Bit(1) in view using conditionals in MariaDB returns 48/49
I'm trying to make a view that appears as BIT(1) type in MariaDB. I tried this answer and did the following:
CREATE FUNCTION CastToBit(N INT) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN N;
END

The problem is, whenever I try to use it conditionally, for some reason it always returns 48 + what would be expected.
SELECT 
    IF(FALSE, CastToBit(1), CastToBit(0)) AS `false`, 
    IF(TRUE, CastToBit(1), CastToBit(0)) AS `true`

Somehow, this returns:



false
true




48
49



Even if BIT(1) shouldn't even be able to store 48 and 49!
If I remove the conditionals, it works:
SELECT CastToBit(0) AS `false`, CastToBit(1) AS `true`




false
true




0
1



I also tried using CASE / ELSE, but no luck.
How can I show the proper numbers inside conditionals?

Which version(s)? I tried the about to be released 10.4.34, 10.5.25and  10.6.18 and got the expected 0,1 response. I see an older version 10.5.17/10.6.9 had an issue (ref fiddle). So this is a bug that has been fixed.

MariaDB, convert automatically to the "best" type in your case ASCII.
So to void it you need another conversion,
but the need to have your function escapes me.
CREATE FUNCTION CastToBit(N INT) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN N;
END


SELECT 
    IF(FALSE, BIN(CastToBit(1)), BIN(CastToBit(0))) AS `false`, 
    IF(TRUE, BIN(CastToBit(1)), BIN(CastToBit(0))) AS `true`





false
true




0
1



fiddle

Works perfectly, thank you! Of course my use case is not IF(FALSE)/IF(TRUE), I just used it as a minimal reproducible example
